# iOS 12.4 -- Cannot inspect PWA in Safari or Safari TP

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I'm getting headache with iOS wherein I cannot inspect my PWA both emulator and simulator.

Here's my specs:

- iOS version - 12.4
- safari version - 12.1.2
- safari tp version - release version 88
- macos version - 10.14.6
- xcode beta - 11.0

any ideas why is this happening? and/or how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As of 12.2, according to [This article](https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945), Apple decided to black-box PWAs running in standalone mode.

In this "In a nutshell" section at the top:

> PWAs in standalone mode are not inspectable anymore with desktop Safari (the Web App process doesn’t appear as inspectable)

You're running 12.4, but I'm not certain if this was intended to have changed since then.